# How to highlight unusual marks on mobile devices

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on sample task where I need to highlight unusual marks on any mobile devices. I'm trying with opencv python. But, I'm not getting actual contors for the unusual marks.

Input image is like:

[image]

And output image is expected as below:
[image]

I'm trying something like below, but it didn't work.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

blurValue = 15
img_path = "input.jpg"

# reading the image 
image = cv2.imread(img_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (blurValue, blurValue), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 255)

#applying closing function 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
lower = np.array([4, 20, 93])
upper = np.array([83, 79, 166])

# hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(hsv, (blurValue, blurValue), 0)

mask = cv2.inRange(closed, lower, upper)
result_1 = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)
cnts = cv2.findContours(result_1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title("image")
plt.show()
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So the expected image you shared is that you did it with drawing or code did it? Or is it the image you want to get at the end?

Comment: expected image, I did in Paint software, not in code.

Comment: To solve this problem in a way that works consistently, it's probably best to build a database with pictures of spotless phones. Then when its time to identify potential problems in a phone, just use Template Matching to automatically identify the brand of the phone and use that image for comparison.

Comment: _but it didn't work._ That's not enough information. In any case, I think this is far too broad/vague, and off topic. See: [ask], [tour], [help/on-topic].

Comment: The solution to your problem should start with detecting the model make of the device, and then comparing the input image with the already stored image of that model and the comparison should be brightness/contrast in-sensetive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use adaptive thresholding and filter on area (and possibly other characteristics). Here is my code and results using Python OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("iphone.jpg")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply gaussian blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (29,29), 0)

# do adaptive threshold on gray image
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 51, 3)

# apply morphology open then close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (17, 17))
open = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(open, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Get contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
result = img.copy()
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 10000 and area > 5000:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)


# write results to disk
cv2.imwrite("iphone_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("iphone_close.jpg", close)
cv2.imwrite("iphone_markings.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("THRESHOLD", thresh)
cv2.imshow("CLOSED", close)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thresholded Image:

[image]

Morphology Processed Image:

[image]

Final Result:

[image]

I would also suggest that you align the image with a known clean iPhone image and create a mask of the camera and logo, etc., markings so that you can filter the results to exclude those (and perhaps even the border of the camera outline).

Comment: [ask], [help/on-topic].